# populate ListView from my database

Tags: android, database, android-listview

I have read so many posts about how to populate the listview from a database. but i simply cant do it on my app! i dont know what im doing wrong. I´m very new to programming so there are allot of things i dont understand but im trying to learn :)

I add items to the database without any problems using this code in the activity:

```
String selectedstone = (String) stonespinner.getSelectedItem();
String weight = etaddweight.getText().toString();

db.addStone(new MyStonesDatabase(selectedstone, weight));
```

in the DatabaseHandler.java i have this:

```
// Adding new stone
void addStone(MyStonesDatabase stone) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_STONE, stone.getStone());
    values.put(KEY_WEIGHT, stone.getWeight());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_MYSTONES, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

I can see that my database gets populated by running this:

```
Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all items..");
List<MyStonesDatabase> items = db.getAllstones();

for (MyStonesDatabase cn : items) {
String log = "Id: " + cn.getID() + ", Stone: "
+ cn.getStone() + ", Weight: " + cn.getWeight();
// Writing Items to log
Log.d("Name: ", log);
}
```

But when trying to have a listview to show the database my app either crashes or dont show anything. In my DatabaseHandler.java i have this:

```
// Getting All items from database
public List<MyStonesDatabase> getAllstones() {
    List<MyStonesDatabase> stoneList = new ArrayList<MyStonesDatabase>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_MYSTONES;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            MyStonesDatabase stone = new MyStonesDatabase();
            stone.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            stone.setStone(cursor.getString(1));
            stone.setWeight(cursor.getString(2));

            // Adding stone to list
            stoneList.add(stone);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return stonelist
    return stone;
}
```

I dont know what to put in my activity that should show the listview.

```
public class MyStones extends ListActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}
```

}

Can someone please help me, im about to give up hehe :)
thanks!

Comment: Can you do us a favor, and post your logcat file, or the error messages? Thanks!

Comment: You are returning `stone` instead of `stonelist` check out your return value `List<MyStonesDatabase>' thats one point

Comment: Your classnames are very misleading... `MyStonesDatabase` is an Item stored inside a Database, but I first thought it is your actual database

Comment: thank you for your replyes. i just realised i need more learning before atempting this, so i bought a few e-books. They are much more easy to learn from then all the tutorials online. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great article/tutorial that might help you. Populating your listView isn't as simple as just doing something in your Activity. You need to create a listAdapter and a couple other things. In the tutorial, they use hard-coded values, in an array. You might try getting that to work, then removing the hard-coded data, and using the data you are getting from your DB.

Getting this to work is a little trickier than you might think, but not overly complicated.

Hope this helps:

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429